# What is a regex "independent non-capturing group"?

Tags: java, regex

From the Java 6 [Pattern](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) documentation:

> Special constructs (non-capturing)
>
> `(?:`*X*`)`   *X*, as a non-capturing group
>
> …
>
> `(?>`*X*`)`   *X*, as an independent, non-capturing group

Between `(?:X)` and `(?>X)` what is the difference? What does the **independent** mean in this context?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It means that the grouping is [atomic](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html), and it throws away backtracking information for a matched group. So, this expression is possessive; it won't back off even if doing so is the only way for the regex as a whole to succeed. It's "independent" in the sense that it doesn't cooperate, via backtracking, with other elements of the regex to ensure a match.

Answer (score 14):

I think [this tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) explains what exactly "independent, non-capturing group" or "Atomic Grouping" is

> The regular expression `a(bc|b)c` (capturing group) matches **abcc**
> and **abc**. The regex `a(?>bc|b)c` (atomic group) matches **abcc**
> but not **abc**.
>
> When applied to **abc**, both regexes will match `a` to **a**, `bc` to
> **bc**, and then `c` will fail to match at the end of the string. Here their paths diverge. The regex with the ***capturing group*** has
> remembered a backtracking position for the alternation. The group will
> give up its match, `b` then matches **b** and `c` matches **c**. Match
> found!
>
> The regex with the ***atomic group***, however, exited from an atomic
> group after `bc` was matched. At that point, all backtracking
> positions for tokens inside the group are discarded. In this example,
> the alternation's option to try `b` at the second position in the
> string is discarded. As a result, when `c` fails, the regex engine has
> no alternatives left to try.

Answer (score 6):

If you have `foo(?>(co)*)co`, that will never match. I'm sure there are practical examples of when this would be useful, try O'Reilly's book.

Answer (score -3):

`(?>X?)` equals `(?:X)?+`, `(?>X*)` equals `(?:X)*+`, `(?>X+)` equals `(?:X)++`.

Taking away the fact that X must be a non-capturing group, the preceding equivalence is:

`(?>X?)` equals `X?+`, `(?>X*)` equals `X*+`, `(?>X+)` equals `X++`.

Comment: The word `independent` in [the Pattern JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is important. They aren't exactly the same, because `(?>X)` doesn't do any backtracking when a partial match fails, so some things that match using one will not match using the other. The [article @erickson linked to was helpful for me.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not into this currently, so maybe my answer is not accurate. But from your own reference: "Most of these also support possessive quantifiers, which are essentially a notational convenience for atomic grouping." This is what I was trying to express. In the latter case, the additional '+' character means the possesive qualifiers.

Comment: `[?/*/+]` is the same as `[?+*/]` and is a [character class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#classes) matching one of the 4 characters (`?`, `+`, `*`, `/`), and the `+` after the `]` is a [greedy quantifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#greedy) that makes the character class match *one or more times*. There is no [possessive quantifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#poss) anywhere in your regex.

Comment: (?>X?) equals (?:X)?+, (?>X*) equals (?:X)*+, (?>X+) equals (?:X)++.

Comment: I don't like this answer because it only works when `X` is itself an atom, and that isn't necessarily the case in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) -- sometimes X _must be an_ an atom (e.g.`X?+`) and sometimes it's not (e.g. `(X)`). Specifically, `(?>X?)` equals `X?+` _only_ if X is an atom: `(?>foo?)` is not equivalent to `(?:foo)?+`.

Comment: Jelaby, where did you read in the doc that X must be an atom in X?+   ? Could you give an example where X would not be an atom in X?+  ?

Comment: I see how negative votes get unanswered, as expected. ?+ Can be applied on anything, atom or not, as long as it's an expression. The same happens with (?> ). You won't apply the rule if X is not an expression: AB?+ is equivalent to A(?>B) not (?>AB?) - apply only on B - and it can't reversely applied on (?>AB?) because AB is not an expression there - B is but (> ) is not directly applied on the result - B? - but on a different expression AB?.  Obviously you have to know precedence to apply a rule. The problem is not atomicity, is using the rule regardless of the expression structure.