# Java regex special construct

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a regex “independent capturing group”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524/what-is-a-regex-independent-capturing-group)

Which is the difference between:

- **(?:X) X, as a non-capturing group and**
- **(?>X) X, as an independent,

  non-capturing group**

I can't figure out how to use the last.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this question:

[What is a regex "independent capturing group"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524/what-is-a-regex-independent-capturing-group)

Comment: Agreed, although this is better suited as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Alright thanks. I'm not 100% on the SO etiquette yet. :)