# Java regex: Normalize all escaped or non-escaped newlines - why does this fail?

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I'm trying to normalize any newlines or escaped newlines in a string to an escaped unix newline. I cannot figure out why this doesn't work:

```
Pattern EOL = Pattern.compile("(\\\\r)?\\\\n|\r?\n");
final String escapedEOL = "\\\\n";

System.out.println(EOL.matcher("asdf\njkl;").replaceAll(escapedEOL));
System.out.println(EOL.matcher("asdf\n").replaceAll(escapedEOL));
System.out.println(EOL.matcher("asdf\r\njkl;").replaceAll(escapedEOL));
System.out.println(EOL.matcher("asdf\r\n").replaceAll(escapedEOL));
System.out.println(EOL.matcher("asdf\\r\\njkl;").replaceAll(escapedEOL));        
System.out.println(EOL.matcher("asdf\\r\\n").replaceAll(escapedEOL));
```

Result:

```
asdf\njkl;
asdf

asdf\njkl;
asdf\n
asdf\njkl;
asdf\n
Done
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?
I realize I could split this into two calls but now I'm curious...

**EDIT**:
Looks like I should have searched harder for [similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712932/bug-in-java-regex-implementation). Looks like quantifiers with groups should be avoided in Java 7.

```
Pattern EOL = Pattern.compile("\\\\n|\\\\r\\\\n|\r?\n")
```

Works also.

Comment: I get different results on Java 8 http://pastebin.com/wHfvMz01.

Comment: Ah, this is on `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)`... I unfortunately can't just upgrade to 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why but changing order in your regex seems to work as you probably wanted, so change

```
Pattern EOL = Pattern.compile("(\\\\r)?\\\\n|\r?\n");
```

to

```
Pattern EOL = Pattern.compile("\r?\n|(\\\\r)?\\\\n");
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/RpO6Lo)

Anyway it looks more like bug than desired behaviour and was changed in Java 8 so there your original regex would also result with

```
asdf\njkl;
asdf\n
asdf\njkl;
asdf\n
asdf\njkl;
asdf\n
```

Comment: How odd. Thanks, looks like I'm going to be triple checking any regex I use in Java from now on...

Comment: Nice troubleshooting, yet another Java regex bug... +1

Answer (score 1):

Grouping the left side of the `|` seems to make things work:

```
Pattern EOL = Pattern.compile("((\\\\r)?\\\\n)|\r?\n");
```

Comment: +1, this is also interesting approach since these outer parenthesis shouldn't have any meaning here.

Comment: @Pshemo removing the optional `?` also makes it work... `\\\\r\\\\n|\r?\n` (but ofc. changes the meaning). The interesting thing is, that the usecase where the pattern fails (`"asdf\n"`) should actually be a match of the *right* side of the pattern, but it stops matching when modifying the *left* side of the Alternation.