# JavaScript RegEx expression for format '0 2 0 2 2'

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am looking for the regEx solution that matches the format of:

number whitespace number whitespace number i.e. `0 2 0 2 2` or `0 10 0 10 4` etc etc

The string can be infinite in length and therefore the expression of the regEx needs to match this however following the same format.

Comment: Not quite as basic as you'd think to do it right :p `^\d+(?>\s+\d+)*$` should do the trick. Are you saying this is basic?

Comment: @Kolink: Yes it is. Just some [repetitions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), two [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), and [grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) :-)

Comment: I have tried a number of solutions that i have found online but no luck. i havent used regex for a while so still trying to get my head around it

Comment: Sorry, had to edit. Needed a once-only subpattern in there.

Comment: @user2373636, Rather than providing the answer for you, it'd be ideal to display the different regular expressions you had attempted which was unsuccessful. This way, we could see where your problem areas are and help to correct and clear any confusion.

Comment: @Kolink Sadly enough JS regex flavor doesn't support lookaround assertions

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV D'oh, I thought this was PHP XD And now I can't edit it back. Damn.

Comment: @Kolink hahaha no problem, removing `?>` should make it work `^\d+(\s+\d+)*$`

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV: Actually it was an ["independent matching group"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/50524/1048572) (to prevent backtracking), not some kind of lookaround (and js supports lookahead, btw). The `(?:` Kolink originally had was perfectly fine…

Comment: @Bergi Ah right, I forget that JS doesn't support lookbehind :p

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV: It is not look-behind. It is non-backtracking group/atomic group, which means that it prevents backtracking. JS regex doesn't have support for this, though.

Comment: @Allendar He doesn't want to split he just want to match the pattern `Number(SpaceNumber)*`.

Answer (score 1):

`/^\d+(\s\d+)*$/` will match number whitespace number whitespace ... number (only one white space)

`/^\d+( \d+)*$/` will match with single space only in between.

These will not match trailing spaces

Comment: You forgot `^` and `$` otherwise this would also match `abc4 88 1`

Comment: Actually it will match `4 88 1` in `abc4 88 1`. Besides I don't know if OP wants it in middle of the string